# rails when/how to use nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a rails app. Users can create products that will be listed on products index page (including some data about the user who posted it) and everybody can see the list on `app/products.html`.

What is the best way to implement this? Should I do it with nested resources (user has many products) in which case I can use `product.user.name` for displaying the user name or should I create an independent class so when user creates a product, some user attributes (name, etc.) will get saved in the product table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mixing together quite a few different concepts here.

### Nested routes

In REST you have a concept of nested resources which is expressed though URIs such as:

```
posts/:post_id/comments # comment that belong to a resource.
```

Which tells us that there is a "has many" relation between `post` and `comments`.

#### The best practice here is that:

- Don't nest if you don't need to.
- Never nest more than 1 level deep. `posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/replies` for example should be `comments/:comment_id/replies`.

### Associations and domain modeling

Domain modeling on the other hand is how your models fit together. In ActiveRecord each model class is backed by a database table.

Each model should correspond to a single type of object in your problem domain. So in your case you would have a User class and Products class.

They would be linked by a `products.user_id` column. So no - you should not store users attributes in the products table.

Comment: You should really start with something like https://www.railstutorial.org/ which explains the basic concepts before trying to build your own app.

Comment: I've read the book before. I know that I'm mixing together, so I asked the question to make sure I will choose the right way. If I save user_id in the products table then rails will know that it's coming from user table without having the has_many/belongs_to relationship? So user name can be displayed as product.user.name?

Comment: No. You need a database column to actually persist the link between `users` and `products` and you also need to tell ActiveRecord what the relation between the two is by declaring `has_many/belongs_to`. Rails will not automatically create associations based on your database schema.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Then how I should deal with the routes? I create the usual nested resources for users `app/users/:user_id/products` where the user actually can see the products he created and on the top of these I should create an `app/products` get route where users can see all the products? I also want users to be able to create a new product on the top of the `app/products ` page (so there is no user param given). I guess I should use there a hidden_field with `current_user.id` right?

Comment: Jees, dude. I'm not going to teach you rails from scratch. There are many ways to pass associations through params.

Comment: Haha. This is the last question, pls make this one straightforward for me.

Comment: Don't use a param for the current user. Do `current_user.products.new` in your controller instead - otherwise someone can tamper with the param. If you want `GET users/:user_id/products` and `GET products` to show different representations you would set up a route for each and hook them up with different controller like `ProductsController#index` and `UserProductsController#index`.

Comment: Thanks max! This last comment helped a lot!